# Calling a view within a view not working properly

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

```
<script src="<?php echo site_url('bootstrapper/jqTimer'); ?>"></script>
```

So I've tried to call the controller below using the script above but I get error not found. Any ideas as to why this method is not working?

```
function jqTimer() {
    $this->load->view("jquery.timers.js");
}
```

Comment: is `jquery.timers.js` is in views directory?

Comment: Yeah... i also tried it as a sub directory, but i usually get errors on that too.

Comment: Is `jqTimer` a method or a function inside your view ?

Comment: it's a controller... it loads the javascript file... then i call the controller inside <script> tags.

Comment: Why you are using ci to load a js? If you invoke a function for this, then combine all your js and call it once.

Comment: I will be once i get all the js written... but i need to have it working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When loading javascript with a `<script>` tag, the `src` attribute is expecting a **file name** to a js file.  You're giving it a path to a controller method in your CI install.

What you need to do is put the `jquery.timers.js` file in the `public_html` folder and access it from there:

```
// assuming you have the script in a [javascripts] folder inside [public_html]
<script src="<?php echo site_url('javascripts/jquery.timers.js'); ?>"></script>
```

If you'd prefer to load your javascript through views, then you need to do this instead:

```
<script><?php echo $this->load->view("jquery.timers.js", "", TRUE); ?></script>
```

This will echo out the contents of the view file between the `<script>` tags for embedded javascript. (*passing `TRUE` as the third parameter returns the content of the file, so you can echo it out*)

Comment: Okay cool I didn't know I could load another view within a view using $this->load->view. Thanks man! Big help indeed!

Comment: FWIW, I would never load a plugin like this as embedded javascript (unless just a few lines of code). One of the main advantages to external files is browser-side caching. By doing it this way, the client will have to download the extra code from the plugin on **every** request.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why you should create a function in the controller just to load a javascript file.
The `base_url()` function can already do what you want.

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('path/to/jquery.timer.js'); ?>"></script>
```

Have a look at the documentation for the [URL helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to echo out a link to the js, not echo out the js itself.
You could create a MY_Controller in the core folder which extends CI_Controller, in which:

```
function jqTimer() {
  return site_url("jquery.timers.js");
}
```

Then, in any other controller (which extends MY_controller) you'd go:

```
$data['js_timer'] = $this->jqTimer();
/* proceed to load main view with $data */
```

View:

```
<script src="<?php echo $js_timer; ?>"></script>
```

This is DRY in that, should you decide to use a different js timer plugin, you need to replace it in one place only: the MY_Controller class (as opposed to every view file).

Still, a bit of an odd way of doing things...